# Submitting without refreshing not on a click of a button but a link

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I pass parameters from one page to the other to be inserted into a table on a click of a link. I want to know if it's possible with ajax to make a call for the insert script on click on the text. I know it's possible with submit buttons but don't know if it's possible with texts containing url parameters.

```vbs
 <table width="586" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><% If Not rs_loguser.EOF Or Not rs_loguser.BOF Then %>
                <span class="style2"><a href="../acc/index.asp"><span class="style6">Your Account</span></a></span>
                <% End If ' end Not rs_loguser.EOF Or NOT rs_loguser.BOF %></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFCCFF" class="style2"><div align="center">
                <% If Not rs_loguser.EOF Or Not rs_loguser.BOF Then %>
                <a href="../topup/index.asp">Account Top up</a>
                <% End If ' end Not rs_loguser.EOF Or NOT rs_loguser.BOF %>
              </div></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFCCFF" class="style2"><div align="right" class="style2">
                <% If Not rs_loguser.EOF Or Not rs_loguser.BOF Then %>
                <a href="<%= MM_Logout %>">Sign Out</a>
                <% End If ' end Not rs_loguser.EOF Or NOT rs_loguser.BOF %>
              </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FF8AFF"><div align="center"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <% 
While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rs_bet.EOF)) 
%>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#CA6BE8"><span class="style8">League: <%=(rs_bet.Fields.Item("leg_type").Value)%>&nbsp;&nbsp; Date: <%= DoDateTime((rs_bet.Fields.Item("rdate_game").Value), 1, 2057) %>&nbsp; Expires On:&nbsp;<%= DoDateTime((rs_bet.Fields.Item("rdate_game").Value), 1, 2057) %>&nbsp;,
                <%
    currdate = DoDateTime((rs_bet.Fields.Item("rdate_game").Value), 3, 16394)
    set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    atb = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\" &_ 
        "Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias" 
    offsetMin = oShell.RegRead(atb)

    %>
                <%=currdate%> </span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="179" bgcolor="#FFCCCC"><a href="../livebet/inter.asp?<%= Server.HTMLEncode(MM_keepURL) & MM_joinChar(MM_keepURL) & "team1=" & rs_bet.Fields.Item("team1").Value %>&amp;game_id=<%=(rs_bet.Fields.Item("game_id").Value)%>"><%=(rs_bet.Fields.Item("team1").Value)%></a></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFCCCC"><div align="center"><a href="../livebet/inter2.asp?<%= Server.HTMLEncode(MM_keepURL) & MM_joinChar(MM_keepURL) & "def_stat=" & rs_bet.Fields.Item("def_stat").Value %>&amp;game_id=<%=(rs_bet.Fields.Item("game_id").Value)%>"><%=(rs_bet.Fields.Item("def_stat").Value)%></a></div></td>
              <td width="210" bgcolor="#FFCCCC"><div align="left" id="team2"><a href="#" id="team2_link"><%=(rs_bet.Fields.Item("team2").Value)%></a>&nbsp;</div></td>
            </tr>
            <% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  rs_bet.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
          </table>
```

Comment: Yes, with ajax you can pass information to server side and get it back, by clicking on any element. Do you have some html you can share to get a more specific answer?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a JQuery example of ajax and the capture of the click event:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() //wait until page is ready.
{    
    //use class, mind the '.' (dot in front of the class name)
    $('.class_of_link').each(function() 
    { 
        $(this).click(function() //fires at click
        {
            alert('starting post');
            //send some data
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "some.php",
                data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
            }).done(function() {
                //do some thing;
                alert('post done');
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please should it be placed below the form? cos i've inserted it in the header and onclick nothing happens. i've even added an alert to it so it tells me it's working but nothing happens?

Comment: Can you post the html of the link as well?

Comment: Ok, i'm pasting it in the question

Comment: yah, i've pasted the whole html and asp now in the question

Comment: @blay : is see your link is in a While loop. The selector  $('#team2_link') might return more then one element. In general you would like to have your ID's unique. I'll update the post to use it with a class.

Comment: thanks very much its working now and i guess if you want to send the parameters of the link i should include it in the data: :{} line

Comment: @blay : yes, keep in mind; if you have problems passing the parameter to the script (e.g. it's different for every row), you can access the `a` element through `$(this).`